# What can cause this exception in apache camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel, catalina

I get this exception at runtime:

```
    org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:290)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1040)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1049)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:422)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.configureMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:876)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:375)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsEndpoint.java:171)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:133)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1941)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:1869)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1662)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1550)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1427)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStart(SpringCamelContext.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1395)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:118)
    ... 32 more
```

And then the rest of the stack trace.

What could cause this exception, knowing that it was working before?

Comment: some more stack trace lines would be helpful :)

Comment: I think you haven't specified jms connectionFactory in your spring context configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified`

You should check your camel JMS component configuration that the connection factory is set to a correct factory.